# Spring security form-login for struts

Tags: spring-security, struts-1

We have struts MVC in our app and want to now integrate spring security.
I am able to integrate it successfully and able to deploy application.

In order to get custom login page we must add form-login to spring security xml file. I am having difficulty in integrating custom login pages.

Struts global forward

```
<global-forwards>
    <forward name="login" path="/" redirect="true"/>
</global-forwards>
```

When not logged in it will take us to login page 
Web xml login config

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.vm</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.vm</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Above section in web.xml is removed as part of integrating with spring security. Rather I have following section in spring security

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE')" />
<form-login login-page="/login.vm" 
            authentication-failure-url="/loginError.vm" />
```

But when I try to login I won't get custom login page rather it just points url to IP:PORT/APP/login.vm and page is not present.

Login form has j_spring_security

```
action="j_spring_security_check"
```

What changes are required in order to get custom login?
Should strut config be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but I suspect that you are getting this as Spring Security does not understand/know about Velocity. I had a similair problem when I intergrated Spring Security into my Struts app using .jsp pages. In the end, I pointed login-page and  authentication-failure-url to point to actions and loaded the jsp pages from there. I suggest that you try the same.

Comment: Should we be giving entire path with form login? like should it be login-page="action.do" should be given? or just login-page="action"?
Since web xml already has 
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

Comment: Tried following. But with no luck
<action path="/auth" type="w.x.y.z.actions.Auth">
 <forward name="success" path="/login.vm"/>
</action>
And in action class override execute  and return action forward "success". But still url is pointed to auth and it says page isn't working

Does the web xml order matters?

Comment: Does it work if you call action auth directly from the browser?

Comment: Also check your intercept-url. I think with the definition as you have it requires that you must have role ROLE to access any url in your application, and you can't have a role assigned until you manage to login. You have to have unfettered access to your login action.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit difficult to diagnose any further without any details of failure messages or stacktraces. I would suggest three things. Firstly switch your logging to debug mode, secondly, change your intercept-url to intercept one specific action only until you get things working. It's easy to block access to stuff you need inadvertantly. Thirdly, use the Struts 2 config-browser plugin and check that Struts has put your login action where you think it is.

Comment: role check for /** was blocking it. so for login I have added permitAll and then checked it. Now it is getting redirected to custom login page. I was inadvertently blocking it by adding role for /**